# Photoshop CC file with missing linked assets?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I got a file from my colleague that I need to edit. When I opened it, I got a message that some linked files were missing.

Upon further inspection, almost all of the layers are called 'Vector Smart Object' and have a red ? on the layer icon. When I try to edit them, I get the following screen:

[image]

But I assume these files are on the other persons local pc, so how do I get access to these linked files?

My colleague is new to photoshop so he has no idea how/why the files are getting linked/not included either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go back to the original computer and ***package*** the file properly. This will include the liked files along with the photoshop file in a location of your choosing.

`File > Package`
Select the location where you want to place the source files and a copy of the .psd (photoshop file).

Or else, on your machine, with the linked files highlighted, look in the properties panel to see the expected (and missing) locations.